# Meteor login using barcode + name+password

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I wanto to implement login using a username & password but also to have a scan of a barcode to complete the login.

Is there a package to do this already (cannot find it on atmosphere); or how would you go about doing it.

The full solution would be to require u+p+b login then timeout the session on a short timeout and require u+p login and timeout the barcode on a longer period to require u+p+b (so login with u+p+b after 15 mins from login require u+p after 60 minutes from login require u+p+b).

The solution needs to work with cordova.

Setup of the account is done via an administration app - so we can assume for the client that the db already has the user set up appropriately.

Thanks,
K.

Answer (score -1):

1. login with u+p
2. check barcode last scanned timestamp in DB
3. if less than specified interval, you should show to user that he has
   to scan the barcode
4. when user scans the barcode, you should call
   server method and update the barcode last scanned timestamp

What kind of scanner are you using? Will this application run in browser on a terminal with scanner?

Comment: "check barcode last scanned timestamp in DB" - you just taught someone how to add a vulnerability.

Comment: I don't have much experience with security, can you please explain this a bit more?

Comment: You have to account to the scenario in which 2 users scan the barcode at very similar times. When you check the last scanned timestamp from the database, it doesn't mean that belongs to the user who is trying to log in. You have to get the scanned barcode by the it's owner and timestamp. The bug where is a "race condition": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition

Comment: Ok, I understand now. Well every user should have its own barcode or at least, every user should have its own last scanned timestamp.